# How to include a user defined function, MakeFolderIfNotExist, in a sub?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I include Ron de Bruin's `MakeFolderIfNotExist` code into my `export_PDF` sub.

If I create an extra sub above it's ignored, if I include it in my original sub I get an error message that the sub is not defined and as a function it's not working either.

```vb
Sub als_PDF_speichern_mac()
        
    ChDir "/" & ActiveWorkbook.Path
    
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
      "/" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/Rechnungen (PDF)/Rechnung_" & ActiveSheet.Range("D11") & ".pdf" _
      , Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
      :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
            
End Sub
```

Ron's sub (customized):
[Source: http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac010.htm]

```vb
Sub MakeFolderTest2()
    
    MakeFolderIfNotExist (ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Rechnungen (PDF)")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Everything from `Function` to `End Function` inclusive must be copied and pasted into your VBA Module. Then you can call it from your export PDF. You don't need the test subs.

Comment: Phew as stupid as I thought, it's working... thank you very much!!

Comment: @StoneGiant If you want to write it as an answer below, I can accept it as the right one to close the question.

Comment: Thanks @Touminator. I have done so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be referencing this web page:

http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac010.htm

(Given concerns about copyright infringement, I will not repost the code here.)

The only portion of the code that you need is everything from `Function` to `End Function` inclusive. Copy that section and paste it into your VBA module. Once you have done that, you can call MakeFolderIfNotExist from your Sub that exports the PDF. You don't need Ron's test subs.